# Writing an array to a file in one row

Tags: c#

Over a serial port I read in some data sent from a weighing scale. It's 8 blocks. That looks like

```
Datum     07.12.2015
Zeit      10:29:43
Artikel   Testxyz
```

and so on.

I manipulate the data and then write it to an CSV file.
My problem is somehow the format of writing the data to the file.
Firstly the data was each written on a new line, so like it was reading in. But I want to have all 8 in one row and then the next block of the 8 information in the new line and so on.
Now it is in one line but therefor I got

```
System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]
```

instead of

```
07.12.2015 10:29:43 Testxyz
```

This problem I had before and fix it but then I haven't got it in one row.
Now I have it in one row but again this  System.String[].
It's frustrating.

Following the code section:

```
public static void Read()
{
    string pathImportFile = @"C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\All Users\Desktop\WaageLAU";
    string pathImportFileDate = "Heute";
    string msgIn = "msgIn";
    string msgInValid = "msgInValid";
    string SpaltenBezeichnungen = "Datum\tZeit\tArtikel\tBrutto\tTara\tNetto\tHoch\tNiedrig";
    string first = "first";
    string second = "second";
    string third = "third";
    string fourth = "fourth";
    string fifth = "fifth";
    string sixth = "sixth";
    string seventh = "seventh";
    string eighth = "eighth";

    // seperators
    string[] Datum = new string[] {"Datum"};
    string[] Zeit = new string[] {"Zeit"};
    string[] Artikel = new string[] {"Artikel"};
    string[] Brutto = new string[] {"Brutto"};
    string[] Tara = new string[] {"Tara"};
    string[] Netto = new string[] {"Netto"};
    string[] Hoch = new string[] {"Hoch"};
    string[] Niedrig = new string[] {"Niedrig"};

    while (_continue)
    {   
        try
            {
                msgIn = _serialPort.ReadLine(); 
            }catch (TimeoutException) { }

        if(msgIn != "msgIn" && msgIn != msgInValid)
        {
            msgInValid = msgIn.Replace("\t", "");

            if(msgInValid != "msgInValid")
            {
                if (msgInValid.Contains("Datum"))
                    {           
                        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");            
                        pathImportFileDate = pathImportFile + " " + date + ".csv";
                        first = msgInValid.Split(Datum, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();  
                    }
                else if (msgInValid.Contains("Zeit"))
                    {second = msgInValid.Split(Zeit, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();}
                else if (msgInValid.Contains("Artikel"))
                    {third = msgInValid.Split(Artikel, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();}
                else if (msgInValid.Contains("Brutto"))
                    {fourth = msgInValid.Split(Brutto, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();}
                else if (msgInValid.Contains("Tara"))
                    {fifth = msgInValid.Split(Tara, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();}
                else if (msgInValid.Contains("Netto"))
                    {sixth = msgInValid.Split(Netto, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();}
                else if (msgInValid.Contains("Hoch"))
                    {seventh = msgInValid.Split(Hoch, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();}
                else if (msgInValid.Contains("Niedrig"))
                    {               
                        eighth = msgInValid.Split(Niedrig, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();                       

                        String[] line = new string[] {first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth};

                        if(!File.Exists(pathImportFileDate))
                        {
                            try
                                {
                                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter fileImport = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathImportFileDate,true))
                                    {
                                        fileImport.WriteLine(SpaltenBezeichnungen);
                                    }       
                                }catch (TimeoutException) { }
                        }

                        try
                            { 
                                using (System.IO.StreamWriter fileImport = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pathImportFileDate,true))
                                {
                                    fileImport.Write(line);
                                }       
                            }catch (TimeoutException) { }
                        Array.Clear(line, 0, line.Length);

                    }
                else
                    {
                        // nichts machen bzw. auf Daten warten
                    }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in in any type of the following line:

```
second = msgInValid.Split(Zeit, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToString();
```

`string.Split(...)` returns a string-array and if you call `ToString()` on a string-array you get the value `string[]` wich is then stored in `second`. You have to save the coresponding value at `.Split(...)[0]` into `second, third, etc.`.

#### The correct line should be:

```
msgInValid.Split(Zeit, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
//or
msgInValid.Split(Zeit, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).FirstOrDefault();
```

`FirstOrDefault` will not raise any errors if there is no entry present in the array.

---

#### Sample:

```
string first = "Datum     07.12.2015";
var k = first.Split(new string[]{"Datum"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
Console.WriteLine(k.Trim());
```

---

## For writing the text correct into a file:

Just replace the code line:

```
fileImport.Write(line);
```

with

```
fileImport.Write(string.Join(",", line));
```

If you want to write each following data-bucket to a new line use `WriteLine`.

> NOTE: this code will not write anything if the serial port does not send or skips the value for *Niedrig*.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same result: System.String[]

Comment: Now I have the real strings and not the System.String[] BUT now the data isn't written in one line but each data-bucket in a new line

Comment: Ok, that might be because each `x.Split[0]` will have a line-break at the end (because of the linebreak in the incoming data). use `string.Join(",", line).Trim(' ','\r','\n')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but the same result as before

Comment: use `debug view` to view what is contained in the `array` and what printed into file.

Comment: I don't use VisualStudio but only programming with notepad++ and use the windows compiler for C#

Comment: small error by my side: use trim when retrieving the data `string.Split(..)[0].Trim(...)` Then you should have the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Why no declare your separators as `String` only instead of `String[]`. And then you can replace `fileImport.Write(line);` with `fileImport.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", line));`

Comment: Why no declare your separators as String only instead of String[]
-> doesn't work with the method string.split
Also with your suggested replacement it gives me the System.String[]